# Excel Max from subset of data MAX IF IF

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, max

I have a set of data as below:

[image]

In the "Latest" Column I want to print "Latest" for the MAX(StepNumber) where tracked = "Yes" for each ManufacuringOrderId. I can try and do this in the SQL, but also wanted to see if I could do it with an array formula. So if this works, the 9th row would say "Latest" and the 4th and 5th rows up from the bottom would also say "Latest".

I tried the formula `{=MAX(IF(A:A=[@ManufacturingOrderId],F:F))}` returns the Max Step Number for each `ManufacturingOrderId`, and the formula `{=MAX(IF([@Tracked]="Yes",IF(A:A=[@ManufacturingOrderId],F:F)))}` will return the max step number for each manufacturing ID that has a process step that is tracked.

However, I can't figure out a way to determine the Max Step number where the process step is tracked for each Manufacturing Order Id.  For Manufacturing Order ID 5601774 the step number would be 160 and for MOID 5624276 the step number would be 150.

help and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the MAX stepnumber for each OrderId when Tracked is "Yes" with this array formula

`=MAX(IF([ManufacturingOrderId]=[@ManufacturingOrderId],IF([Tracked]="Yes",[StepNumber])))`

....so to to get "Latest" in the correct rows you need to check that not only does Stepnumber = that value but also that "Yes" exists in that row, i.e.

`=IF(AND([@StepNumber]=MAX(IF([ManufacturingOrderId]=[@ManufacturingOrderId],IF([Tracked]="Yes",[StepNumber]))),[@Tracked]="Yes"),"Latest","")`

confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

**Revised:** This version should be more efficient - using two `IF`s, rather than `AND` means the long `MAX(IF` part of the formula only needs to be evaluated on rows where `[Tracked]="Yes"`

`=IF([@Tracked]="Yes",IF([@StepNumber]=MAX(IF([ManufacturingOrderId]=[@ManufacturingOrderId],IF([Tracked]="Yes",[StepNumber]))),"Latest",""),"")`

[Note AND here is used to check 2 single result conditions, not within the array part]

Comment: What's your experience using array formulas.  I am running in bootcamp on a new Retina MBP.  I am trying to copy this formula down 532 lines of data and I am getting the "excel has run out of resources" error message.

Comment: Array formulas can be inefficient but I wouldn't expect problems with just 532 rows, I suggested a slight change to the formula in my answer that should be more efficient....

Comment: I was able to solve the problem without the use of an array formula. I used a separate column and check for any processes after the current one that had a quantity.  If there was one I set the current Qty to zero. If not I summed all quantity with the same step number and Manufacturing Order number as the current line.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly then you should be able to AND the two conditions (that each row is of the same ID as the current row and that it is Tracked) inside the MAX. Then just check whether that number matches the current `StepNumber` and say "Latest" if it is.

```
{=IF(MAX(IF(AND(A:A=[@ManufacturingOrderId], [@Tracked]="Yes"),F:F)) = [@StepNumber], "Latest", "")}
```

Comment: I solved my own problem, but tried your solution and it did work so thank you very much.  My solution is below as well:

Comment: I've found my own solution, but unfortunately can't post it for another 7 hours.  If someone else posts it in the meantime I will choose it as the answer.

Comment: There are 2 problems with this solution, you can't use AND in array formulas and get the expected results (the result of AND is a single value TRUE/FALSE not an array of results as required). You need to use multiple IFs as per formula in question (or use * to simulate AND). Also even with that fix you are only checking that any row equals that value, it doesn't check whether that row is "Yes" or "No", so if you have "Yes" or "No" rows with the same value it can give erroneous results - see my answer for a formula that should work in all circumstances